# Changing colors and icons dynamically without reseting the app

Tags: react-native, theming

In my app, I used such a system for theming.

I have a `Images.js` file which contains objects with requires. Im using image files as icons btw.

For example for the header I have something like,

`const imagesHeader = {back: require("path/back_icon.png"),next: require("path/next_icon.png")}` and so on.

But now I need also a dark theme. For that, Im holding a observable variable in my `app` store. Btw, Im using `MobX` for state management. I have a store called app and I have a observable variable called theme like so: `@persist @observable theme = "light"` and It's value is `light` by default.

But, in RN i realized that once you require an icon as a image when your component is initialized, you cannot change it dynamically without reseting your app.
For that i decided to make every single image `getter function` like:

First of all I grab all the images in a single object called `allImages`

```
const allImages = { 
   light mode ->     light:{
                            back: require("path/light/back_icon.png"),
                            next: require("path/light/next_icon.png")},
   dark mode ->      dark:{
                            back: require("path/dark/back_icon.png"),
                            next: require("path/dark/dark/next_icon.png"),
                };
```

after that, i get my variable from my store and return in like so,

```
   const getTheme = () => getStores().app.theme; <- returns "light/dark" (string)
```

and finally in the imagesHeader instead of using require like above, I use like:

```
const imagesHeader = {
            get back(){ return allImages[getTheme()].back
            get next(){ return allImages[getTheme()].next
                     };
```

**I followed same logic for colors too, not only for the icon images. I created getter method for every single color as like as I created getter for every single icon here**!!

But the problem is now, I think It's trying to require my `theme` variable from the store, before the store actually initialized.
Becouse I always created the styles definitions outside of the class/functional components. But a `MobX` store initialize while the actual component initializing, which means I can reach to the `theme` value when the component is initialized. Otherwise i get `theme is undefined` error.
I also made some researches for that, and found a way, so If I convert my `styles` definitions to functions, It's actually waiting for component to initialize.
as you know,  normally we are defining styles like so:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

This is NOT working,

```
const styles = () => StyleSheet.create({});
```

This is working.
But If I convert all the styles in the whole project which has 600+ files, I need to use styles in the tags like `styles().something` instead `styles.something`.

Actually everything working fine but my main question to get better ideas from you becouse I dont want to spent my time while editing 600+ files :(

If there Is a better way to handle this or If there is a way to initialize my `MobX` stores before the components would be great to know.
Or maybe there is a better logic, to handle these stuff.

Thank you!